# ROR + Detect ClassName from text-field & Replace it by another one

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

In TextField of Ruby Code, I want to check whether the specified class is applied or not, on blur event. Please suggest some technique or way. Sample code is given below used by me.

Ruby Code for TextField::

```
    <%=f.text_field :Username, :size=>4, :tabindex=>2, :class=>class_name, 
:autocomplete => "off", :onblur=> $$$$$ %>
```

Suppose class_name : 'changeView' is applied on above textfield, then I have to detect this particular class & replace by another one like 'changeExtraview'. By using any of the javascript, we can replace that class name but suggest if you have any better option.

Thanks

Comment: This is possibly rails' code, instead of 'Ruby Code'

Comment: Ya buddy, its Rails Code

Comment: This is a javascript question, not a rails one. Checking for field blur is a client side issue, RoR can NOT help you there. Retagged to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guessed answer...

So your `class_name` might be contain a value of `changeView`, and if in the case, you want to replace the `changeView` class name to `changeExtraview`, right?

If it is, then the following should be ok:

```
<%=f.text_field :Username, :size=>4, :tabindex=>2, :class=>class_name.gsub(/changeView/, "changeExtraview"), :autocomplete => "off", :onblur=> $$$$$ %>
```

========================

Another try:

```
<%=
  f.text_field :Username, :size=>4, :tabindex=>2, :class=>class_name, :autocomplete => "off",
    :onblur => "if($(this).hasClass('changeView')) {$(this).removeClass('changeView'); $(this).addClass('changeExtraview')}"
%>
```

========================

As @Faisal pointed out, using binding in JS side would be better. Although the answer was long time ago, I decided to update the answer again:

```
<%= f.text_field :Username, :size => 4, :tabindex => 2, :class => class_name, :autocomplete => "off" %>
```

And in any ways (I use content_for in this example), add the following js code:

```
<%= content_for :javascripts do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("<%= class_name %>").bind("blur", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('changeView')) {
          $this.removeClass('changeView');
          $this.addClass('changeExtraView');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Note that the above code requires you have `<%= yield :javascripts %>` in your layout file,

Comment: @PeterWong :: Hey Buddy, At the time when page loads, changeView will be the class for that textfield, but at the time of blur event, i wanna set className as changeExtraview.

Comment: Ya I am agree with you. But Is it possible in ROR, then it's fine otherwise I have to use Javascript !!

Comment: Error occured by .hasClass is not a function

Comment: This is the answer you want, however I would enhance it by removing the intrusive javascript part. Do not add the code as an attribute of the field. Give the field a class or ID, and bind a javascript event to change the css class for the field.

Comment: @Rahul Patil, `hasClass` is a jQuery function. @Faisal, I agree with your point. Writing inline javascript in rails code would definitely make the code ugly.

Comment: Did this answer not help you?